# multiplication of elements of each tuple in a list with each element of a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

For a given list of tuples and a list of the integers, how to get a resulting list ("L3") of tuples where each new tuple will be a result of a multiplication of the elements of the tuple in L1 and L2.

```
L1 = [(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(6,3,4),(9,8,7)]
L2 = [20,55,90]
L3 = [(20, 110, 270), (40, 165, 360), #and so on ]
```

Comment: Use the `map()` function or a list comprehension.

Comment: Do you know that `len(L1[0]) == 3` or just that `len(L1([0]) == len(L2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the dimensions of L2 are going to match the Tuple dimensions of L1.
using numpy broadcast operations it can be done as an array multiplication.

```
L1 = [(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(6,3,4),(9,8,7)]
L2 = [20,55,90]

import numpy as np

M1=np.array(L1)
V1=np.array(L2)

print(f"M1 dimension is {M1.shape} \n V1 dimensions are {V1.shape}")

R=V1*M1
result=[tuple(x) for x in list(R)]
```